# jQuery to hide an element but it's not working

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a page in SharePoint (aspx). I am trying to hide a td control using jQuery. I have attached the rendered html from developer tool and the jquery. jsFiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/savo0mme/1/

html code

```
<table class="ms-WPBody" style="padding-top: 0px; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;"></td><td id="ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage" width="100%" style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;">The default value specified is not valid.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
 </table>
```

jquery code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var filterErrorText = "ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage";
        var filterErrorTextID = document.getElementById(ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage).innerText;
        alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage").innerText);
        alert(filterErrorTextID);
    /*  if(filterErrorTextID)
        {
            alert(filterErrorTextID);
            //filterErrorTextID.style.display="none";
        } */
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt of yours to hide a `td` element. You have 2 ones here but it's unclear which one exactly it is. If you really want to hide it, you should have Googled for the solution first and I'm sure you should have solved this yourself.

Comment: Don't mix DOM calls with your jQuery. Use one or the other. You probably want `$('#' + filterErrorText).hide()`

Comment: Just an advice : Never use Ids like this "ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage" in sharepoint to target an element. Always use  div[id$="_DefaultValueMessage"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not use jquery.
You should use jQuery hide() function like

```
$('#ctl00_m_g_1c59424a_162b_4285_8f9a_33109bdfc04f_DefaultValueMessage').hide();
```

Comment: jQuery hide function works perfectly. However, I have to evaluate whether that control contains text or not. that's why I was trying alerts with innerHtml or innerText but none would work

Comment: With jQuery, there is the .text() function
It return the inner text.